# What's the difference between Omniauth gem and Omniauth-Provider gem?

Tags: omniauth, omniauth-facebook

Just starting to think through authentication now, wondering what's the diff between Omniauth from Intridea, and all the single provider options like Omniauth-Facebook.

It seems to me like if Omniauth allows for multi-provider, it should also allow for single-provider, in which case using it is almost always a better option because you never know when you want to add another provider later on, whereas with something like Omniauth-Facebook, if you decide to add something else at a later point you have to backtrack.

Answer (score 1):

Omniauth is the base library which other libraries (like omniauth-facebook) build on top of to provide authentication using an actual serve (like Facebook).  Omniauth itself only comes with a fake authentication service called `Developer`.  You have to use omniauth-facebook, omniauth-twitter etc. depending on which service you want to allow your users to log in using.  You can use as many of them as you want in the same project -- using omniauth-facebook does not limit you in any way -- want twitter auth as well? -- just add omniauth-twitter to your Gemfile (for a rails/bundler project).

I think the README for omniauth is fairly clear on this in the Introduction section:

https://github.com/intridea/omniauth

and the omniauth github.io page shows a Gemfile with multiple strategies used at the same time in the Getting Started section:

http://intridea.github.io/omniauth/

Answer (score 0):

[OmniAuth](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth) is a framework that allows you to authenticate against as many identity providers as you please. You create or use a separate "strategy" for each provider you authenticate with.

So you would install the `omniauth` gem and then any of the strategy gems for providers you wish to use, such as `omniauth-facebook` or `omniauth-slack` for example.

OmniAuth provides a [list of strategies](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/List-of-Strategies) that can be used with OmniAuth v1.0 or later.